# Why does my router slow down my Internet speed?

Tags: wireless-router

I have an ASUS RT-N66R Wireless router with which I have been happy for over a year.  Yesterday, for no reason that I can determine, the internet speed through the router slowed from its acceptable 5mbs to .2mbs.  I have rebooted the router numerous time, updated the firmware and fiddled with some of the settings and nothing I do has improved the situation.  Id don't know what else to do.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: [How to Fix Your Wi-Fi Network: 7 Tips](http://www.pcworld.com/article/260524/how_to_fix_your_wi_fi_network_7_tips.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have tagged this wireless, so, I'll make an assumption that is how you connect.

Have you tried connecting via wire/ethernet to see if you get a good speed?

As for wireless, it could be one of a number of things, the most common being that

1. Your Laptop/Desktop have been nocked and antenna misaligned/broken,
2. Your equipment is unfortunately old and just underperforming because of degradation/
3. Interference... Have you got any new cordless phones/microwave/lights etc.?
4. Your neighbor may have new wireless equipment that is interfering with yours.

Number one can be hard to diagnose, you can rule it out by connecting your device to a mobile phone or another wireless device to make sure it is working.

Number two is awkward again - I would test via ethernet to rule out the wireless being the issue.

For number three and four, try changing your wireless channel and/or download a program that can scan wireless channels to see what is the least congested in your area.

Comment: Yes, I have directly connected to the Internet.  That is how I generated the speed comparison.  My desktop is hard-wired to the router, everything else is wireless. No new equipment in the last 30 days.  The channel was set to auto.  I changed it to 10, made no difference.  The nearest neighbor is a mile away.  My ISP is wifi through a radio.

Comment: I recommend that you try to speed test from your desktop to another device if you can... ideally use something like Iperf (let me know if you need instructions). If it is a wireless backhaul provider, then, the most likely cause is that they are having the issues with 3/4, or, it could just be the bane of most ISPs, plain old congestion